# How to detect which view was clicked in Android

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener

I have a `LinearLayout` which contains two `RelativeLayouts`.

Here is the XML code:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/SaleSwithcBarView_navigation_bar_LinrearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/SaleSwithcBarView_users_created_bar_button_RelativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/SaleSwithcBarView_users_favorite_bar_button_RelativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Now I am trying to detect with `clickListner` which view (from this two `RelativeLayouts` was clicked), I have tried to do it like this (java code):

```
navigationBar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {   
            @Override
            public void onClick(View navigationButton) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "hope here: " + navigationButton.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                switch (navigationButton.getId()) 
                {
                    case USER_CREATED_BUTTON_ID:
                        Toast.makeText(context, "here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        switchTodDisplay(USER_CREATED_BUTTON_ID + BINDER_OFFSET);
                        break;

                    case USER_FAVORITE_BUTTON_ID:
                        Toast.makeText(context, "or here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        switchTodDisplay(USER_CREATED_BUTTON_ID + BINDER_OFFSET);
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
```

the `navigationBar` is the `LinearLayout` and the `USER_CREATED_BUTTON_ID` (it is `final int`) is the id of the left `RelativeLayout` and `USER_FAVORITE_BUTTON_ID` is the id of the right `RelativeLayout`. Both id's I have assigned programmatically like this:

```
userCreatedSalesBarButton.setId(USER_CREATED_BUTTON_ID);
userFavoriteSalesBarButton.setId(USER_FAVORITE_BUTTON_ID);
```

So how can I detect which of the `LinearLayout` child views was clicked. I don't want to create a `clickListeriner` for each `RelativeLayout`.

Thanks

Comment: What is navigationBar? It looks like you're trying to set OnClickListeners for buttons, but I don't see any buttons defined in your XML. If you want to detect which one of your TextViews was selected, you can just set individual listeners for those TextViews. Not sure what you're going for here, though

Comment: EDIT: I see navigationBar is the LinearLayout. Are you trying to detect which RelativeLayout was selected? Or which TextView inside each RL was selected

Comment: Which relativelayout was selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want to create a clickListeriner for each RelativeLayout.

You can use a single `OnClickListener` implementation, but you are going to have to actually assign the `OnClickListener` to the widget for which you want to find out when it is clicked.

Either:

- Convert your existing `OnClickListener` anonymous inner class to be a regular inner class, then create two instances of that inner class to use for each of your "buttons", or
- Store your instance of your `OnClickListener` anonymous inner class in a data member, then use that data member in `setOnclickListener()` for each of your "buttons"